# Ansible - Nested Loop Dict Variables

Tags: loops, ansible

I am working on a playbook to create several bridge domains on each of several Cisco ACI hosts. I have my playbooks laid out as follows:

Outer Play:

```yaml
- include_tasks: bridge_domain.yml
  loop: "{{ bridge_domains }}"
  loop_control:
    loop_var: outer_item
```

Inner Play:

```yaml
- name: Add Bridge Domain - L2
  cisco.aci.aci_bd:
    host: "{{ item.value.hostname }}"
    username: "{{ username }}"
    password: "{{ password }}"
    validate_certs: no
    tenant: TNT_Test
    bd: "{{ item.value.formatted_name }}"
    description: "{{ item.value.formatted_name }}"
    arp_flooding: yes
    bd_type: ethernet
    l2_unknown_unicast: flood
    vrf: "{{ item.value.VRF }}"
    enable_routing: false
    state: present
  delegate_to: localhost
  with_dict: "{{ outer_item.value.sites }}"
```

Vars File:

```yaml
---
# vars file
bridge_domains:
  BD_1:
    #common variables
    Descriptor: testbd1
    Zone_3CHR: ABC
    Subzone_3CHR: DEF
    District: GHI

    #site specific variables
    sites:
      Test_1:
        hostname: testhost1
        VRF: th1_VRF
        formatted_name: "{{ Zone_3CHR }}-{{ Subzone_3CHR }}-T1-{{District}}-{{Descriptor}}"
      Test_2:
        hostname: testhost2
        VRF: th2_vrf
        formatted_name: "{{ Zone_3CHR }}-{{ Subzone_3CHR }}-T2-{{District}}-{{Descriptor}}"

  BD_2:
    #common variables
    Descriptor: testbd2
    Zone_3CHR: JKL
    Subzone_3CHR: MNO
    District: PQR

    #site specific variables
    sites:
      Test_1:
        hostname: testhost1
        VRF: th1_VRF
        formatted_name: "{{ Zone_3CHR }}-{{ Subzone_3CHR }}-T1-{{District}}-{{Descriptor}}"
      Test_2:
        hostname: testhost2
        VRF: th2_vrf
        formatted_name: "{{ Zone_3CHR }}-{{ Subzone_3CHR }}-T2-{{District}}-{{Descriptor}}"
```

The problem comes with creating the formatted_name variable. I know the issue is that I'm trying to self-reference within a dict. How can I change my variable file or my playbook to correctly create a formatted_name that is different per bridge domain and per test host? Thanks!

Edit: The error message I get is

```
FAILED! => {"msg": "'Zone_3CHR' is undefined"}
```

Edit 2: Updated to the following per Alexander's suggestion, but now only bd_2 is created on each host.

hosts.yaml:

```yaml
---
# hosts-dev.yaml
bridge_domains: # parent group
  vars:
    ansible_connection: local
    tenant: TNT_TEST
  children:
    bd_1:       
      vars:     # common variables specific to bridge domain
        Descriptor: testbd1
        Zone_3CHR: ABC
        Subzone_3CHR: DEF
        District: GHI
      hosts:
        testhost1: # site-specific variables
          VRF: VRF_T1
          formatted_name: "{{ Zone_3CHR }}-{{ Subzone_3CHR }}-T1-{{District}}-{{Descriptor}}"
        testhost2:
          VRF: VRF_T2
          formatted_name: "{{ Zone_3CHR }}-{{ Subzone_3CHR }}-T2-{{District}}-{{Descriptor}}"
    bd_2:       
      vars:     # common variables specific to bridge domain
        Descriptor: testbd2
        Zone_3CHR: ZYX
        Subzone_3CHR: WVU
        District: TSR
      hosts:
        testhost1: # site-specific variables
          VRF: VRF_T1
          formatted_name: "{{ Zone_3CHR }}-{{ Subzone_3CHR }}-T1-{{District}}-{{Descriptor}}"
        testhost2:
          VRF: VRF_T2
          formatted_name: "{{ Zone_3CHR }}-{{ Subzone_3CHR }}-T2-{{District}}-{{Descriptor}}"
```

Playbook:

```yaml
---
- name: Configure the bridge domains
  hosts: bridge_domains
  connection: local
  gather_facts: False
  vars_prompt:
    - name: "username"
      prompt: "enter username"
      private: no
    - name: "password"
      prompt: "password"
      private: yes
  tasks:
    - name: Add Bridge Domain
      cisco.aci.aci_bd:
        host: "{{ inventory_hostname }}"
        username: "{{ username }}"
        password: "{{ password }}"
        validate_certs: false
        tenant: "{{ tenant }}"
        bd: "{{ formatted_name }}"
        description: "{{ formatted_name }}" # probably you want to generate something different here        
        vrf: "{{ VRF }}"
        state: present
      delegate_to: localhost
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define an [inventory](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/inventory_guide/intro_inventory.html) with group and/or host variables instead of looping over nested structures. `formatted_name` isn't the only issue - even if you manage to fix it, you will then try to iterate over a hash instead of a list, and will still miss the flexibility and maintainability that inventories provide.

Consider this simplified example:

```yaml
---
# hosts.yaml
bridge_domains: # this is a parent group
  vars:         # variables and templates common for all bridge domains go here
    ansible_connection: local # because you don't SSH into the hosts as I understand
    formatted_name: "{{ Zone_3CHR }}-{{ Subzone_3CHR }}-{{ other_important_value }}-{{District}}-{{Descriptor}}"
    tenant: TNT_Test
  children:
    bd_1:       # this is a group for BD_1 bridge domain
      vars:     # common variables specific to BD_1 bridge domain
        Descriptor: testbd1
        Zone_3CHR: ABC
        Subzone_3CHR: DEF
        District: GHI
        other_important_value: T1
      hosts:
        testhost1:
          VRF: th1_VRF # variables specific to the testhost1 host
        testhost2:
          VRF: th2_vrf # variables specific to the testhost2 host
    bd_2:       # this is a group for BD_2 bridge domain
      ... # similar structure here
```

If your configuration is more complex, you can move the variables to `group_vars` and `host_vars` directories accordingly.

Using this approach, you should be able to use the module in a way as specified in the [examples](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/cisco/aci/aci_bd_module.html#examples):

```yaml
---
- name: Configure the bridge domains
  hosts: bridge_domains
  tasks:
    - name: Add Bridge Domain
      cisco.aci.aci_bd:
        host: "{{ inventory_hostname }}"
        username: "{{ username }}"
        password: "{{ password }}"
        validate_certs: false
        tenant: "{{ tenant }}"
        bd: "{{ formatted_name }}"
        description: "{{ formatted_name }}" # probably you want to generate something different here        
        vrf: "{{ VRF }}"
        state: present
      delegate_to: localhost
```

**EDIT:**
As @NotGene clarified, there will be multiple bridge domains, but only a limited amount of hosts, and the relationship is not `1:1` as I supposed initially. There are multiple ways to solve this but to keep things simple, we can create a list of BDs, but move the description template directly to the module invocation:

The inventory file will be like this:

```yaml
---
aci_hosts:
  vars:
    ansible_connection: local
    tenant: TNT_TEST
    VRF: "VRF_{{ T }}"
    formatted_name: 
    bridge_domains:
    - name: BD_1  
      Descriptor: testbd1
      Zone_3CHR: ABC
      Subzone_3CHR: DEF
      District: GHI
    - name: BD_2
      Descriptor: testbd2
      Zone_3CHR: ZYX
      Subzone_3CHR: WVU
      District: TSR
  hosts:
    testhost1:
      T: T1
    testhost2:
      T: T2
```

And the playbook:

```yaml
---
- name: Configure the bridge domains
  hosts: aci_hosts
  connection: local
  gather_facts: False
  vars_prompt:
    - name: "username"
      prompt: "enter username"
      private: no
    - name: "password"
      prompt: "password"
      private: yes
  tasks:
    - name: Add Bridge Domain
      cisco.aci.aci_bd:
        host: "{{ inventory_hostname }}"
        username: "{{ username }}"
        password: "{{ password }}"
        validate_certs: false
        tenant: "{{ tenant }}"
        bd: "{{ bridge_domain.name }}"
        description: "{{ bridge_domain.Zone_3CHR }}-{{ bridge_domain.Subzone_3CHR }}-{{ T }}-{{ bridge_domain.District }}-{{ bridge_domain.Descriptor }}"
        vrf: "{{ VRF }}"
        state: present
      delegate_to: localhost
      loop: "{{ bridge_domains }}"
      loop_control:
        loop_var: bridge_domain
```

This will create two BDs per each host:

```
TASK [Add Bridge Domain] *********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [testhost1] => (item={'name': 'BD_1', 'Descriptor': 'testbd1', 'Zone_3CHR': 'ABC', 'Subzone_3CHR': 'DEF', 'District': 'GHI'}) => {
    "msg": "Bridge domain BD_1: ABC-DEF-T1-GHI-testbd1"
}
ok: [testhost1] => (item={'name': 'BD_2', 'Descriptor': 'testbd2', 'Zone_3CHR': 'ZYX', 'Subzone_3CHR': 'WVU', 'District': 'TSR'}) => {
    "msg": "Bridge domain BD_2: ZYX-WVU-T1-TSR-testbd2"
}
ok: [testhost2] => (item={'name': 'BD_1', 'Descriptor': 'testbd1', 'Zone_3CHR': 'ABC', 'Subzone_3CHR': 'DEF', 'District': 'GHI'}) => {
    "msg": "Bridge domain BD_1: ABC-DEF-T2-GHI-testbd1"
}
ok: [testhost2] => (item={'name': 'BD_2', 'Descriptor': 'testbd2', 'Zone_3CHR': 'ZYX', 'Subzone_3CHR': 'WVU', 'District': 'TSR'}) => {
    "msg": "Bridge domain BD_2: ZYX-WVU-T2-TSR-testbd2"
}
```

Comment: Thanks! The only problem is that the format of formatted_name may need to change slightly from host to host. For example, on testhost1 we may want it to be as shown above, while on testhost2 having the component variables in a different order or omitting certain ones. Is it possible to make that formatted_name var specific to each host?

Comment: Sure. Ansible has multiple levels of variable precedence. In particular, this means that on the host level you can override the variables defined on the group level.

Comment: It seems as though when I format my inventory like that and run the play like you specified, only the last bridge domain is created on each host. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I've edited my original post to show what I have now for playbook and inventory

Comment: It's because the hosts in `bd_1` and `bd_2` groups are the same and the `formatted_name` seem to coincide completely - is it expected? Maybe I understood your idea incorrectly.

Comment: I may have been unclear in my intentions, no worries. I have several ACI hosts. They are redundant copies of each other, just with different naming conventions. So I want to automate creation of new Bridge Domains, creating very similar BDs on each host, just with slightly different formatted names. So there are only two hosts, and I want to create bd_1, bd_2, bd_3, etc. on each one with the name and VRF changed per host

Comment: Initially I thought that the BDs and hosts should have `1:1` relationship, so I grouped the hosts by BDs. But Ansible flattens the variables to the host level so in case of `1:n` relationship they will get overwritten. So, there are two options. One - define unique host aliases but explicitly set `ansible_host` variables to `testhost1` and `testhost2` for each pair if my grouping criteria is still valid. Or - adjust the inventory structure and define a common group variable that stores a list of BDs and interate over it (basically, return to your idea but simplify it by keeping the inventory).

Comment: I edited my answer to match your requirements.